# Is there a formal definition for 'digits per term'?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I've seen the phrase 'digits per term', mostly with regards to algorithms that produce $\pi$. I've seen it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283270/how-do-i-determine-whether-my-calculation-of-pi-is-accurate/14283481#comment19836495_14283481) ("Yes, Chudnovsky's formula converges at a steady 14.18 digits per term."), on numerous [formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) for $\pi$ ("This gives 50 digits per term", "...converges at only one bit/term") and on [source code](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/libmp/gammazeta.py#L95) involving Khinchin's constant. I've fiddled with one of the algorithms, and it *appears* that it's -log(value of ratio test)/log(10), but I don't know why it's that value nor if it would be true for any method.

The phrase itself implies a linear convergent series, but could it be used on any converging series? It also seems to be more than just saying a series converges linearly or quadratically. For instance, given a series, could I say something like "it produces $≈0.7503$ digits per term" or "$0.023n^2$ correct digits per $n^{th}$ term are found"?

Just what exactly is it (if there is a definition for it) and how is it determined? Just where are these numbers coming from? Searching for said phrase just leads me to stuff about $\pi$.

Comment: So what don't you understand in the context of those particular references? As far as I can see, those references are all about series approximations and "digits [or bits] per term" makes good sense. I agree that you might be working series which converge too slowly or too quickly for this to be a useful measure, so you might want to say that the $n$-th term adds $f(n)$ digits of additional precision for some non-constant function $f$. I don't see why you think the concept of the number of digits of precision added by each term in a series needs any more detailed definition.

Comment: @RobArthan Where do these numbers even come from?